# Is there a way to see all comments I have made on Youtube/googleplus?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I have my posts public on youtube/googleplus, basically the same entity now, and I can't find a way to see all of the comments I have made. I have been at this for about an hour and feel like an idiot. The best thing I have found so far involved searching based on usernames or content. Normally, I don't complain with a big change to something like youtube. Change is always hard/new, but this interface is infuriatingly obtuse.

Is it possible to see ALL of the youtube comments one has made in the past, preferably in chronological order?

Or do I just have to wait until they randomly bubble up to the top of my googleplus page?

Isn't googleplus/google+ a terrible choice for a name that has to be referenced by typing symbols into search enginges where plus/+ has a different meaning than the word 'plus'? Google is straight slipping with this one.

Comment: +1 This would be nice to have, i suggested auto play from one of my 3 youtube accounts and i cant find it now!

Comment: By Dec 2020, it's as simple as clicking on hamburger menu (top left corner), click on "History" and click on "Comments" on the right of your screen.

Answer (score 5):

Try a Google search using this query:

**site:youtube.com "your username" inurl:all_comments**

Replace ***your username*** with your YouTube user name.  Keep the quotes around it, though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good attempt but, unfortunately, it picks up all the "In reply to [your username]" comments.

Comment: A nice google dork, but it picks up partial username matches. For instance, my username "C Smith" also matches people like "Robin C Smith". I guess with some refinement it might work, I would have to look further at current google dork syntax.

Comment: Works good enough for me!

Answer (score 1):

It's currently **not possible** to see all the comments you've ever made.

However, if you haven't unchecked the "Also post to Google+" checkbox when you write a comment, you should be able to see all the comments you've ever made on YouTube in your G+ profile at *plus.google.com/+[your username or id]/posts*.